Building docker interactively
I was trying to build a docker container using Apptainer. I have a long list of R packages to be installed with specific versions. I need to install it from CRAN/BioConductor directly and not from conda. Now, for each package I try to install, I might hit a roadblock due to missing libraries and then have to go back and add it using apt install. This becomes an iterative process and takes a long time. Is there an interactive way to build the container. I was trying using sandbox and fakeroot but it does not get the full capabilities to write while installing the system libraries. What other solution can I integrate?
Bootstrap: docker
From: ubuntu:22.04
%labels
    Author author_name
    version v0.1

%post 
    export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
    
    # Update system and install requirements
    apt-get -qq update
    

    apt -y install build-essential gfortran curl cmake pkg-config zip unzip \
                   libglib2.0-0 libpango-1.0-0 libpangocairo-1.0-0 libpaper-utils \
                   libtcl8.6 libtk8.6 libxt6 lmod 
    
    apt -y install libbz2-dev libicu-dev liblzma-dev libopenblas-dev libpq-dev \
                   libpcre2-dev zlib1g-dev libssl-dev libudunits2-dev libncurses-dev libcairo2-dev \
                   libsodium-dev libmariadb-dev libcurl4-openssl-dev libssh2-1-dev libxml2-dev \
                   libfreetype6-dev libpng-dev libtiff5-dev libjpeg-dev libfontconfig1-dev \
                   libharfbuzz-dev libfribidi-dev liblapack-dev libgit2-dev libmagick++-dev 
    
    
    curl -o /tmp/libicu60_60.2-3ubuntu3.2_amd64.deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/i/icu/libicu60_60.2-3ubuntu3.2_amd64.deb
    dpkg -i /tmp/libicu60_60.2-3ubuntu3.2_amd64.deb

  
    # Install R with all recommended 
    export R_VERSION=4.2.2
    curl -o /tmp/r-${R_VERSION}_1_amd64.deb https://cdn.rstudio.com/r/ubuntu-2204/pkgs/r-${R_VERSION}_1_amd64.deb
    dpkg -i /tmp/r-${R_VERSION}_1_amd64.deb

    ln -s /opt/R/${R_VERSION}/bin/R /usr/local/bin/R
    ln -s /opt/R/${R_VERSION}/bin/Rscript /usr/local/bin/Rscript


    # Install the R packages
    
    R -e 'install.packages("remotes", dependencies = TRUE, repos = c("https://cloud.r-project.org/", "http://rforge.net/"))'
    R -e 'remotes::install_version(package = "BiocManager", version = "1.30.22", dependencies = TRUE, repos = c("https://cloud.r-project.org/", "http://rforge.net/"), upgrade = "never")'

    R -e 'remotes::install_version(package = "dplyr", version = "1.1.4", dependencies = TRUE, repos = c("https://cloud.r-project.org/", "http://rforge.net/"), upgrade = "never")' 
    R -e 'remotes::install_version(package = "ggplot2", version = "3.5.1", dependencies = TRUE, repos = c("https://cloud.r-project.org/", "http://rforge.net/"), upgrade = "never")'  ##### downgraded to 3.4.3
    R -e 'remotes::install_version(package = "ggpubr", version = "0.6.0", dependencies = TRUE, repos = c("https://cloud.r-project.org/", "http://rforge.net/"), upgrade = "never")' 


In my experience, the iterative practice of installing R / Py packages, revealing missing system packages, installing the system package, and trying again is unavoidable!
I agree it's easier to develop and test interactively.  This is possible by a docker run --rm -ti [image name] bash to get a bash shell interface into the container from the built image.
I believe it's also possible with docker exec if the container is already running with a different CMD statement.
Then, you can launch the R console with $ R and then try the > install.packages().  And if it complains about a system package, > quit() and do the $ apt get install ... or whatever appropriate for your OS.  And then try again.
Finally, add all package install commands you found were necessary to your Dockerfile.
docker build -t my_image .
docker run --rm -ti my_image bash


It's the same command with docker exec if the image is running, e.g. docker exec -it [image name] bash.  Also if you want to be able to run sudo commands, it's sometimes useful to add -u root. However, I don't think this workflow is inevitable anymore, at least on Ubuntu. I haven't needed to do it since I switched to r2u.

Use compiled binaries
As you're using Ubuntu, an alternative approach would be to use the Ubuntu binary versions of CRAN packages provided by r2u. This has several advantages, as set out in the docs:


Full integration with apt as every binary resolves all its dependencies: No more
installations (of pre-built archives) only to discover that a shared library is missing. No more
surprises.
Full integration with apt so that an update of a system library cannot break an R package:
if a (shared) library is used by a CRAN, the package manager knows, and will not remove it.  No
more (R package) breakage from (system) library updates.
Simpler and lighter than some alternatives as only run-time library packages are installed as
dependencies (instead of generally heavier development packages).
Installations are fast, automated and reversible thanks to the package management layer.


What this means in practice is that you do not need to bother with all the apt install libssl-dev steps, as you can start with the r2u docker image, and add whichever packages you need. This means your Dockerfile will be much simpler, and you will not find yourself missing important system libraries.
How it works
This can be done with three files:

Dockerfile.
install.r.
pkgs_to_install.txt

Dockerfile
This looks like:
FROM eddelbuettel/r2u:noble
WORKDIR /r
COPY install.r .
COPY pkgs_to_install.txt .
ENV TZ=Europe/London
RUN ln -snf /usr/share/zoneinfo/$TZ /etc/localtime && echo $TZ > /etc/timezone
RUN Rscript install.r

You may wish to set the time zone to your local area.
pkgs_to_install.txt
List the packages you wish to install. In your case it could be:
dplyr
ggplot2
ggpubr
BiocManager

install.r
You can include in this whatever you want to customise your R profile, including installing packages:
pkgs_to_install <- readLines("./pkgs_to_install.txt")
install.packages("remotes")
remotes::install_github("REditorSupport/languageserver") # to prevent vscode warnings
Sys.setenv(R_INSTALL_STAGED = FALSE) # prevents occasional 00LOCK permissions issues
for (pkg in pkgs_to_install) {
    try(install.packages(pkg))
}

My real setup is slightly more complex. I have an additional R script which runs at the end which makes a few small changes to the R profile and also writes out the output of installed.packages() to a csv, so it is clear which version of each package is installed in the container.
The overall point, though, is that it is easy to add whatever features you like with this workflow. It should also avoid the dependency nightmares that seem inevitable with the various C++ libraries that certain packages require. Also, as all the packages are installed from pre-compiled binaries, rather than source, it is much faster to build.
As this answer may seem extremely zealous, I should perhaps add that, except as a user, I have no affiliation to r2u or its docker container.

As mentioned, this one install.packages() to install the most recent version of the package. How well does it perform with install_version() if I need to specify a specific version?

@ArindamGhosh it's a good question - I haven't tried it. I think you'd lose most of the benefits of the alignment with the package management system. I would think the better way to do it would be to select, say, the 20.04 tag from the docker tags, and then you should get the right package versions. But I haven't tried this approach with older versions of R so I'm not really sure - if you give it a go then please provide an update as it may be helpful for others who are looking at this issue.
